# Using SQL query to add dynamic content to table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

db_nameI am trying to add content to the MySQL data base by using JSON API.

```
 INSERT INTO `ersmdb_cartpauj_pm_messages`
 (from_user, to_user, message_contents, message_read, date) 
 VALUE (CASE WHEN from_user THEN {userid} 
 AND to_user THEN {myid} 
 AND message_contents THEN {message} 
 AND message_read THEN 1 
 AND date THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

But getting an error when my URL query is: www.domain.com/api/addcontent/?userid=1&myid=2&message=hello

Has anybody got an idea how to add dynamic content to VALUE as:

```
 VALUE ('1','2','hello','1',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: What does the error message say?  What are the types of the columns in your table?

Comment: it says: Query has something error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 2 AND message_contents THEN hello AND message_read THEN 1 AND da' at line 1","result":[]})

Comment: Look more closely at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) for the `insert` statement.  The VALUES should be a comma-separated list, not `AND`-separated.

Comment: dg99 it didn't help when I changed ANDs to commas

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
INSERT INTO ersmdb_cartpauj_pm_messages(from_user, to_user, message_contents, message_read, date) 
    SELECT {userid}, {myid}, {message}, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I'm not sure what the `case` logic is supposed to be doing with an `insert`.  All the fields are needed.